# Symfony 2.8 vhost: www/ directory instead of project index

Tags: symfony, apache2, vhosts

i started new project on symfony 2.8.2.
I added on my apache2 sites/enabled this vhost file, copied from symfony cookbook:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.n-difference.fr
    ServerAlias local.n-difference.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/n-difference/web
    <Directory /var/www/n-difference/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/project/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I did sudo service apache2 restart to refresh the server.
I access the project from another Dev PC with ssh, and of course, i added on this etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.1.20 local.n-difference.fr
```

The problem is when i try to access the url local.n-difference.fr, i have this www/ index page
[image]
Did i forget something ?

Thank's a lot for your help :)
(and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @goto copy/paste error, it's local.n-difference.fr in my conf, and the problem  still exists. I edited the post

Comment: It seems like it does not go through your vhost file. Did your do `sudo a2ensite yoursite.conf` ?